# IBOutlet in protocol implementaion

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, swift-protocols

I have the following protocol:

```
protocol TextViewInputField {
   var indexPath: IndexPath? { get set }
   var textView: UITextView { get set }
   var lblPlaceHolder: UILabel { get set }
   func updatePHHiddenState()
}
```

a cell `TMStyle2Cell` implements this protocol as follows:

```
class TMStyle2Cell: UITableViewCell,TextViewInputField {

    @IBOutlet var lblPlaceHolder: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var viewSeperator: UIView!
    var indexPath: IndexPath?

    func updatePHHiddenState() {

    }
}
```

Why am I getting the following error?

> `TMStyle2Cell` does not confirm to protocol `TextVeiwInputField`.

Answer (score 14):

The types in your protocol and your implementation aren't matching. You need:

```
protocol TextViewInputField {
   var indexPath: IndexPath? { get set }
   var textView: UITextView! { get set }
   var lblPlaceHolder: UILabel! { get set }
   func updatePHHiddenState()
}
```

If you use weak IBOutlets, you also need to include that:

```
protocol TextViewInputField {
   var indexPath: IndexPath? { get set }
   weak var textView: UITextView! { get set }
   weak var lblPlaceHolder: UILabel! { get set }
   func updatePHHiddenState()
}
```

Finally, small point, but the `set` part of your protocol probably isn't necessary.

Comment: You shouldn't include `weak` in Swift 4.1. If you do, the compiler will warn you to remove it (`'weak' should not be applied to a property declaration in a protocol and will be disallowed in future versions`).

Answer (score 9):

Example of protocol. Tested in Swift 4.2.

```
@objc protocol ImageRepresentable {
    var imageView: UIImageView! { get set }
}
```

And for view.

```
class ViewA: UIView, ImageRepresentable {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

For your case.

```
@objc protocol TextViewInputField {
    var indexPath: IndexPath? { get set }
    var textView: UITextView! { get set }
    var lblPlaceHolder: UILabel! { get set }
    func updatePHHiddenState()
}
```